# In this boost asio example why is the io_service started after .async_accept is called

Tags: c++, boost-asio

question is simple(my boost asio knowledge is really bad, so it is probably trivial):
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html

Why is io_service started *after* we already executed ctor that does async_accept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's the most convenient way to write this code. There's no harm in starting asyncronous operations before their completion can be handled, as long as they are handled at some point. If they complete before the service starts, then they are queued until it does.

The constructor *could* dispatch the `start_accept` function to the `io_service` if you really wanted to defer it until the service is running, but that would just add extra complication, and a delay, for no benefit.

Comment: can you specify precisely what you mean by  starting and handling? starting is async accept and handling is running the registered handler by io_service?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Yes, by "starting" I mean the user calling a function like `async_accept` to start an asyncronous operation. By "handling", I mean the `io_service` calling the completion handler that was provided when the operation was started.

Comment: btw if it was the other way around would .run return immediately ? I know this sounds noobish, but this io_service is kind of weird to me with me comming from the past (sockets, sockets, threads, sockets, threads)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Yes, `run` returns when there's no work to do; so if you haven't started an asyncronous operation, posted some work, or created an `work` object before calling it, then it will return immediately.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Important to remember here is: If your io_service has ever returned, you need to call its `reset()` member function before it can be `run()` again or it will always return instantly and do nothing.

Comment: ok, noted.... any reason for this, i doubt it is bad design so it must have a reason ?

Answer (score 3):

The `io_service::run()` function blocks until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched. If `io_service::run()` has nothing to do it returns immediately. So you need to provide some work before starting. Like it does in boost example:

```
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp_server server(io_service);   // <-- prepares async task
    io_service.run(); // <-- blocks 
} // <-- all done
```

Ok, lets try to call `run` before `tcp_server` instantiation

```
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    io_service.run(); // <-- returns immediately
    tcp_server server(io_service);   // <-- prepares async task
} // <-- async task is cancelled (or its result is lost)
```